# How to use libarchive properly?

Tags: c++, zip

I'm trying to zip/unzip folders using libarchive. But, I couldn't know how to use it?

Comment: Go look at the documentation of libarchive maybe? :)

Comment: @NathanMonteleone, I haven't understood the process!

Answer (score 8):

Include these:

```
#include <archive.h>
#include <archive_entry.h>
```

And compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -o test test.c -lz -lbz2  -larchive
```

So all together it should look something like this

```
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <archive.h>
#include <archive_entry.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int
copy_data(struct archive *ar, struct archive *aw)
{
  int r;
  const void *buff;
  size_t size;
  off_t offset;

  for (;;) {
    r = archive_read_data_block(ar, &buff, &size, &offset);
    if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
      return (ARCHIVE_OK);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
      return (r);
    r = archive_write_data_block(aw, buff, size, offset);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(aw));
      return (r);
    }
  }
}

static int
extract(const char *filename)
{
  struct archive *a;
  struct archive *ext;
  struct archive_entry *entry;
  int flags;
  int r;

  /* Select which attributes we want to restore. */
  flags = ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_TIME;
  flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_PERM;
  flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_ACL;
  flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_FFLAGS;

  a = archive_read_new();
  archive_read_support_format_all(a);
  ext = archive_write_disk_new();
  archive_write_disk_set_options(ext, flags);
  archive_write_disk_set_standard_lookup(ext);
  if ((r = archive_read_open_filename(a, filename, 10240)))
    return 1;
  for (;;) {
    r = archive_read_next_header(a, &entry);
    if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
      break;
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(a));
    if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN)
      return 1;
    r = archive_write_header(ext, entry);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
    else if (archive_entry_size(entry) > 0) {
      r = copy_data(a, ext);
      if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
      if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN)
        return 1;
    }
    r = archive_write_finish_entry(ext);
    if (r < ARCHIVE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", archive_error_string(ext));
    if (r < ARCHIVE_WARN)
      return 1;
  }
  archive_read_close(a);
  archive_read_free(a);
  archive_write_close(ext);
  archive_write_free(ext);
  return 0;
}

int main ( int argc, const char **argv )
{
  return extract (argv[1]);;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this link will help? [Examples from LibArchive Wiki](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples)

For example, here is the code they give to write files to an archive:

```
void
write_archive(const char *outname, const char **filename)
{
  struct archive *a;
  struct archive_entry *entry;
  struct stat st;
  char buff[8192];
  int len;
  int fd;

  a = archive_write_new();
  archive_write_add_filter_gzip(a);
  archive_write_set_format_pax_restricted(a); // Note 1
  archive_write_open_filename(a, outname, 10240);
  while (*filename) {
    stat(*filename, &st);
    entry = archive_entry_new(); // Note 2
    archive_entry_set_pathname(entry, *filename);
    archive_entry_set_size(entry, st.st_size); // Note 3
    archive_entry_set_filetype(entry, AE_IFREG);
    archive_entry_set_perm(entry, 0644);
    archive_write_header(a, entry);
    fd = open(*filename, O_RDONLY);
    len = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    while ( len > 0 ) {
        archive_write_data(a, buff, len);
        len = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    }
    close(fd);
    archive_entry_free(entry);
    filename++;
  }
  archive_write_close(a); // Note 4
  archive_write_free(a); // Note 5
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
  const char *outname;
  argv++;
  outname = argv++;
  write_archive(outname, argv);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to include that lib into that project? Would you please provide a full code ?

Comment: From the man page of `archive_write_free`: `Invokes archive_write_close() if necessary, then releases all resources. ...`